# Laravel assertViewIs with view from a package

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-10

I have multiple packages that make up a CMS built on top of Laravel 10. In this example: a UI package and a core package.

In my `core` I define this route, which returns a view from my UI package:

```php
Route::get('php-test', function () {
   return view('my-cms::dashboard.home');
});
```

I want to test this route, so in the `composer.json` of my core package I add the UI package:

```json
"require-dev": {
    "my-cms/ui": "dev-master"
},
```

Then I write a test in my core package which contains this test method:

```php
/** @test */
public function test_route_returns_view() : void
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    
    $response = $this->get('php-test');
    $response->assertOk();
    $response->assertViewIs('my-cms::dashboard.home');
}
```

This returns the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException: No hint path defined for [my-cms].

In the ServiceProvider of the UI package I register the views:

```php
public function boot() : void
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', 'my-cms');
}
```

How can I test if a route returns a view, when that view is from another package?

Comment: did you run `composer install`? is this package you are requiring discoverable?

Comment: Yes, the package is installed and is also discoverable. I fixed it by adding the service provider of the package to the `getPackageProviders()` function of the tests that require it. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is error is thrown because I guess the ServiceProvider isn't ran when the package is not installed in an actual application. Not sure if this is the best solution but it works.

In the tests that use other packages I register the ServiceProvider of the other package:

```php
protected function getPackageProviders($app) : array
{
    return array_merge(
        parent::getPackageProviders($app),
        [\MyCms\UI\MyCmsUIServiceProvider::class]
    );
}
```

This makes it so that the views are getting registered and the error dissapears.